# Anchor Tag Mailto Breaking / Disabling Click Events, target="_blank" Behavior Suboptimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, anchor, mailto

I've been running into a weird issue when clicking on an anchor tag with a mailto: href while using Outlook, further click events on the page where not going off.  Not clicking on the link would allow further click events to work correctly.

I couldn't get it to happen locally for the longest time, so on a gut feeling I changed the target on the anchor tags to `target="_blank"` to open up in a new window.  This seems to have fixed the issue, however now the open window that launched the email client stays open after the client loads.

So I need help with one of two things.  One, is there a way of having a mailto: open on another page and have it auto close after the email client "catches"?  If this isn't possible, what could be causing the mailto: to break jQuery/ Backbone.js events?  Where would I start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still haven't pinned down what caused this, but I'm done looking for it.  Just answering here to clean up my questions.